# How to move to next image in ViewPager, if the current image is in zoomed state in TouchImageView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touchimageview

I am using [`TouchImageView`](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) by Mike Ortize with my custom `ViewPager` as suggested by Mike Ortize.

My question is, how to scroll to next image in `ViewPager` if the current image is in zoomed state ?

Currently, in my implementation the `ViewPager` takes to next screen only after zooming out the image. I am using `getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean);` to control the switching of the touch event handling between `TouchImageView` and my custom `ViewPager`. If I don't do it then I can not pan the image horizontally, as the viewpager takes me to next image.

One solution I think of is, getting the edges of `Image` & `ImageView` and detecting the direction of scroll. Then using this,switch the touchlistener from `TouchImageView` to its Parent `ViewPager`.

I got this idea from [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library by Chris Banes.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I did refer to the question [View Pager + ImageView +Pinch Zoom + Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20943831/1554935)

For the custom ViewPager I am referring to [Answer by Mike Ortize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944068/1554935)

Comment: What did you mean by Custom ViewPager? I use normal ViewPager, and it swipes even if TouchImageView is zoomed.

Comment: When you swipe back, it maintains the zoomed status as well.

Comment: Please take a look in to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830296/how-to-reset-the-zoomed-image-into-original-image/33270676#33270676

Comment: i'm having exact problem like you, did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: @RuchaBhatt, No I have not..otherwise I would have posted it. If you find any then please post here.